# Application did not close cursor or db object was opened here

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am using SQLite database in my android application. When i do search operation then randomly I found this error "Application did not close cursor".is there any thing wrong with this code?. Here is the code

```
    field.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    String test = s.toString().trim();
                    if (test.isEmpty()) {
                        if (myCursor != null)
                            myCursor.close();

                        myCursor = getReceipts1Data(orderTypes);
                    myAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(activity, myCursor, CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);
                    lView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                    }
                }
            });


 public Cursor getReceipts1Data(Global.OrderType[] orderTypes) 

    {
        String subquery1 = "SELECT ord_id as _id,ord_total,ord_issync,cust_id,isVoid,ord_type" +
                " FROM Orders WHERE ord_type IN (";
        String subquery2 = ") AND isOnHold = '0' ORDER BY rowid DESC";
        Cursor cursor = DBManager.getDatabase().rawQuery(subquery1 + getOrderTypesAsSQLArray(orderTypes) + subquery2, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see the line where you close the cursor if it is null, but i can't see the one where you are closing it if it is not null. To be more specific, have you tried adding

```
myCursor.close();
```

after the line:

```
lView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

in the onTextChanged method